# Elf file read symbol and symbol address 1 byte difference

Tags: c++, elf, armv7

A few days ago, i looked through the elf symbol table to compare strings to find a my function.
I could find the target string well and I succeeded in getting the starting offset and size.
However, when comparing this offset with the result of objdump, it can be seen that 1 byte is different.
what is wrong?
I'm not good at English well.

os : windows 10 
ide : **android studio ndk** 
target arch : **armeabi-v7a**

result image : 
**application result : 0x00908b5

expected result :   0x00908b4**

What I checked :

1. elf32_sym, elf64_sym checked (no problem)
2. struct byte padding checked (no problem)
3. struct, variable initialization checked

[image]

This is a clone from a developer's git.

```
template <typename ElfHeaderT, typename SectionHeaderT, typename CallbackT>
void read_sections(const void *image, size_t size, const CallbackT &callback)
{
    const ElfHeaderT *ehdr = static_cast<const ElfHeaderT *>(image);
    const SectionHeaderT *shdrs = (const SectionHeaderT *)((const uint8_t *)image + ehdr->e_shoff);
    const SectionHeaderT *strhdr = &shdrs[ehdr->e_shstrndx];
    const char *strtab = static_cast<const char *>(image) + strhdr->sh_offset;

    for (int i = 0; i < ehdr->e_shnum; ++i)
    {
        section s = {0,};

        s.index= i;
        s.name = strtab + shdrs[i].sh_name;
        s.type = shdrs[i].sh_type;
        s.virtual_address = static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(shdrs[i].sh_addr);
        s.file_offset = static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(shdrs[i].sh_offset);
        s.size = static_cast<size_t>(shdrs[i].sh_size);
        s.entry_size = static_cast<size_t>(shdrs[i].sh_entsize);
        s.address_align = static_cast<size_t>(shdrs[i].sh_addralign);
        callback(s);
    }
}


template <typename SymbolEntryT, typename CallbackT>
void read_symbols(const void *image, unsigned int code_section_index, const section &symbols, const char *names,
    const CallbackT &callback)
{
    const size_t total_syms = symbols.size / sizeof(SymbolEntryT);
    const SymbolEntryT *syms_data = (const SymbolEntryT *)((const uint8_t *)image + symbols.file_offset);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < total_syms; ++i)
    {
        symbol s = {0,};
        const SymbolEntryT &sd = syms_data[i];
        const unsigned type = ELF32_ST_TYPE(sd.st_info);

        if (type != STT_FUNC)
            continue;
        if (sd.st_shndx != code_section_index || !sd.st_size)
            continue;
        s.name = names + sd.st_name;
        s.size = static_cast<size_t>(sd.st_size);
        s.virtual_address = static_cast<size_t>(sd.st_value);
        callback(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not 100% certain here, but I think the low bit indicates thumb code.  So branching to 0x00908b5 actually sets pc to 0x00908b4 but starts executing thumb code at that address.

Comment: I know that THUMB Mode is 16 bit bit command set. I need more detailed knowledge, can you explain it further?

Comment: Yes Thumb mode, read this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293238/arm-mode-and-thumb-mode-makes-the-pcs-bit-0

Comment: I have checked the contents of Thumb mode. If so, can I subtract 1 from the calculated function offset?

Answer (score 1):

Instructions must be aligned to their natural boundaries, which means that 16-bit instructions must be 2-byte aligned and 32-bit instructions must be word-aligned.  (There's more to it than this but this is the important bit for the purposes of this question.)  Therefore the least-significant bit of a branch target must always be zero, and effectively the LSB contains no information.

When the 16-bit Thumb instruction set was introduced in parallel with the 32-bit ARM instruction set in the armv4T devices (starting with the ARM7TDMI), this unused bit was repurposed to indicate whether code should be interpreted in ARM mode or Thumb mode following a branch.  The function was still located in the same place either way, with the LSB being effectively cleared in hardware to create the true branch target, but its value controlled the instruction decode mode following the branch.

Since the introduction of the unified Thumb-2 instruction set, this mechanism is no longer used.  But Thumb-2 is considered a descendant of the Thumb instruction set, not of the ARM instruction set, and (for example) a Cortex-M target is considered to be running in Thumb mode permanently.  The LSB of an address is therefore required to be set when that address is used as a branch target.  If it's not set, you'll get a fault because the CPU thinks it's being asked to execute 32-bit ARM code which it doesn't support.  The same goes for the Thumb bit in xPSR, which must remain set at all times.

So to answer your question, nothing is wrong at all.  If you want to know where your function is located so you can inspect it in a memory window or something, then use the even-valued address.  If you want to execute a branch manually, for example by using a hard-coded numeric branch target in assembly code, make sure you use the value with the LSB set.